# Deleting Correct Row on Button Click

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, sql-delete

I have a 4 column table in my program with one of the columns being a column with a delete button for each row. Whenever I click the delete button, I want it to delete the corresponding row and send a delete query via AJAX that deletes that row in the database.

What seems to be happening now is whenever I click the delete button, it is deleting the row above it, or if I delete the top row where there is no row above it, it does not delete at all, which I do not want.

I get no errors in my console. I do get a successful `row deleted` message each time though even though.

So how can I fix this problem and get the delete working so that it deletes the row that corresponds to where the button is?

HTML for table along with delete button:

```
<table id="skuTable" cellspacing="5" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
        <th class="skuRow">SKU Group</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Group ID</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Edit</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

    <tr>
        <td class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Group'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU Group'];?></td>
        <td class="group_id" align="center" id="group_id-<?php echo intval ($row['Group_ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Group_ID'];?></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>

</tbody>
```

JavaScript:

```
function deleteRow(r) {

if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("skuTable").deleteRow(i);
  }


    request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "delete.php",
      data: "Group_ID="+i
    });


        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row deleted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to delete");
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });


}
```

delete.php:

```
<?php

  $SKU_Group = $_POST['SKU Group'];
  $Group_ID = $_POST['Group_ID'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $delete = "DELETE FROM SKU_Group_Dim WHERE Group_ID = '$Group_ID'";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($delete);
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  echo json_encode($result);
  if(!$result) {
      echo sqlsrv_errors();
  }

?>
```

Comment: there probably isn't enough HTML in the question. If you're using a form for this or not treated as an array, there may not be a hidden element for it (the row), which is a method often used.

Comment: I posted the HTML for the table that the delete button is included in if that helps at all...I am using a form in my program but it does not include the table as it deals with a search functionality

Comment: you have `id="group_id` with `group_id` in lowercase but using `data: "Group_ID="+i` with `Group_ID` in mixed case. Sounds to me like that's what the problem is, or a contributing one. The lettercase must match.

Comment: ok so that meant nothing then ^

Comment: The Group_ID is the actual name of the column in the DB so that is why that is like it is....would the casings definitely have to be the same?

Comment: @Rataiczak24 aren't you using Jquery, I will post you a very good solution of it if you are using Jquery on your page, I recommend u must do

Comment: @HaiderAli Yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have table header that has rowIndex zero while actual row starts then from rowIndex one. e.g.

```
 request = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "delete.php",
  data: "Group_ID="+i+1
});
```

Edited answer since I read the problem too fast.

Comment: Check what console log prints for the variable i when clicking delete.

Comment: the `console.log(i)` logs 1 when i try and delete the first value

Comment: How are items in db ? Do items start from zero or one ?

Comment: The column is not an auto incrementing column. However, the first value in that column starts at 2.

Comment: However I would avoid this kind of tight ties between UI and DB. This issue actually proved how fragile it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your database when you delete a row. Is the row successfully deleted  the one you want deleted? If so then the problem isn't  with the data being passed to the database but your javascript is not getting the right i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowindex needs changing.

In your html

```
<?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

    <tr value = "<?php echo $row['Group_ID'];?>">
```

then in your JS to avoid using the rowIndex use the

```
i = r.parentNode.parentNode.value()
```

Actually I would use different calls here than parentNode but trying to stick to your code

otherwise your problem would be with the value of group_id that is passing into the database and isn't matching the values of the indices in the html table whether that be i or i+1

Comment: I get an error saying that `r.parentNode.parentNode.value()` is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Problem look like is in your JS code, considering you HTML is correct output I just changed last row by removing on click event and adding a data-group-id attribute also added a class on table row

```
<table id="skuTable" cellspacing="5" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
        <th class="skuRow">SKU Group</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Group ID</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Edit</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

    <tr class="row<?php echo intval($row['Group_ID'])?>" >
        <td class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU Group'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU Group'];?></td>
        <td class="group_id" align="center" id="group_id-<?php echo intval ($row['Group_ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Group_ID'];?></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="delete" data-group-id="<?php echo intval($row['Group_ID'])?>">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>

</tbody>
```

Below JS code

```
   $(".delete").on("click", function() {
     var group_id = $(this).data("group-id");
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "delete.php",
      data: "Group_ID="+group_id,
      success: function(response) {
             if(response == true)
                  $(".row"+group_id).remove();
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
      }
    });

   });
```

If you get error please comment
Thanks